# Different between AWS boto3.session.Session() and boto3.Session()

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to use AWS python library boto3 to create a session. I found out we can do that either

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile1')
```

or

```
session2 = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='profile2')
```

I have checked their [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html), it suppose to use **boto3.session.Session()**.

Why both ways work ? What the different of concept behind them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just for convenience; **they both refer to the same class**.  What is happening here is that the `__init__.py` for the python boto3 package includes the following:

```
from boto3.session import Session
```

This just allows you to refer to the Session class in your python code as boto3.Session rather than boto3.session.Session.

This [article](https://mikegrouchy.com/blog/be-pythonic-__init__py) provides more information about this python idiom:

> One common thing to do in your `__init__.py` is to import selected Classes, functions, etc into the package level so they can be conveniently imported from the package.

Comment: Thanks! I got the concept now!