# I'm trying to type annotate around boto3, but module 'botocore.client' has no attribute 'EC2'

Tags: python, boto3, python-typing

I'm writing my own wrapper around boto3 for quick firing functions.

I'm trying to type annotate what `boto3.session().client('ec2')` returns.

Debugger says it's `<class 'botocore.client.EC2'>`, but if I write it down like that, python crashes with a runtime error

```
ec2: botocore.client.EC2
AttributeError: module 'botocore.client' has no attribute 'EC2'
```

Removing type annotation works for runtime, but it makes linting very limited.

Is there a reasonably fast way or a hack to get typing working with this boto3 case?

The code I'm talking about is following:

```
class AWS_Client:
    # debugger says it's <class 'botocore.client.EC2'>,
    # but mypy says this class does not exist
    ec2: botocore.client.EC2
    asg: botocore.client.AutoScaling
    region: str
    instance_id: str

    def __init__(self,
                 profile_name: Optional[str] = None,
                 instance_id: str = '',
                 region_name: str = '',
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        global config

        self.instance_id = instance_id or ec2_meta('instance-id').text
        self.region = region_name or ec2_meta(
            'placement/availability-zone').text[:-1]
        boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level=logging.DEBUG)
        self.session = call_partial(
            boto3.Session,
            region_name=self.region,
            profile_name=profile_name,
            **kwargs)
        self.ec2 = self.session.client('ec2', region_name=self.region, **kwargs)
        self.asg = self.session.client(
            'autoscaling', region_name=self.region, **kwargs)

    def get_tags(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        self.tags = self.ec2.describe_tags(Filters=[{
            'Name': 'resource-id',
            'Values': [self.instance_id]
        }])['Tags']
        return self.tags

aws = AWS_Client()
print(aws.get_tags())
```

Comment: Are you creating the session correctly? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html  With my version of boto3, I need to use boto3.session.Session().client('ec2') if only using import boto3

Comment: I guess you're right according to docs, but currently there's no difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540959/1421036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [mypy-boto3](https://pypi.org/project/mypy-boto3/) mypy plugin.

You can install it via

```sh
python -m pip install 'boto3-stubs[ec2]'
```

```py
import boto3
from mypy_boto3_ec2 import EC2Client


def foo(ec2_client: EC2Client) -> None:
    ...


ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")

foo(ec2_client)  # OK
```

Comment: thank you, `boto3-stubs` and proper annotations is what I needed. I even had `types-boto3` installed (which is boto3-stubs proxy) and imported but haven't actually read its docs because I was assuming it should just work after installing.